# Wagtail single-page site

Tags: python, html, django, wagtail

I made a single-page site in static HTML with shiny screen-height divs, and a smooth scrolling function from a navbar. The website is expected to have a mixture of simple body text, a few images, and a card-deck. It all worked nicely and I was happy.

While I have used wagtail for very simple websites in the past, I cannot work out a way of making a single page site where the home page goes at the top followed by all the child pages in order. Is this possible with Wagtail's page models?

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding correctly: you want a setup where the content is entered in the backend as multiple pages, but on the front-end it appears a single page, with the content of all pages output one after the other...?

Comment: Yes, annoyingly I have to do them as separate pages in the backend because, while there are fixed types of data (title + body text, title + cards, etc.) there are unknown numbers of these and I want to leave them with flexibility to add, remove, or reorder sections/pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done something like this a while ago by rendering subpages of my `HomePage` class as section on this `HomePage`. There was some minor customization at various places involved (see below). Perhaps the hardest part was rewriting the page-urls of the "section pages" to point to the `HomePage` and the correct anchor on this `HomePage` (see below `get_url_parts`).

I've recycled the wagtail page class build-in `in_menu` to generate a navbar with/to the relevant sections.

While I've been trying to catch everything, I hope nothing relevant has slipped my mind...

## Code

### models/pages.py

```py
class HomePage(Page):
    """
    We only have one frontend page, on which we render child pages as subsections.
    """

    parent_page_types = [
        'wagtailcore.Page',
    ]
    # The following page types (here named "sections") are standard wagtail 
    # page models, but rendered on this HomePage.
    subpage_types = [
        'TextSection',
        'WhereSection',
        'ContactSection',
        ...
    ]

    # fields...
    # panels...

    def get_subsections(self):
        """
        Return page queryset with sections to render on the HomePage.
        """
        return (
            self
            .get_children()
            .specific()
            .live()
            .public()
        )

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['subsections'] = self.get_subsections()
        context['nav_sections'] = self.get_subsections().in_menu()
        return context
```

### models/sections.py

```py
class BaseSection(models.Model):
    """
    BaseSection abstract base class. All HomePage sections should inherit
    from this class.
    """

    parent_page_types = ['HomePage']
    subpage_types = []

    fields...
    panels...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def get_url_parts(self,  request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Customising URL patterns for a page model
        http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/topics/pages.html#customising-url-patterns-for-a-page-model
        Rewrite page path to corresponding anchor of this section on the 
        containing page.
        """
        url_parts = super().get_url_parts(request=request)

        if url_parts is None:
            return None
        else:
            site_id, root_url, page_path = url_parts
            _cust_page_path = '#section-{}'.format(page_path.replace('/', ''))
            return (site_id, root_url, _cust_page_path)


class TextSection(BaseSection, Page):
    template = 'sections/text_section.html'

    body = RichTextField()

    content_panels = BaseSection.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body'),
    ]

class FooSection(BaseSection, Page):
    ...
```

The rest is done via the template layer: looping over all subsection on the homepage:

```html
# templates/home_page.html

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block navbar %}
  {% include 'includes/navbar.html' %}
{% endblock navbar %}

{% block page_content %}
    {% for subsection in subsections.all %}
       {% with subsection.specific as subsection %}
          {% include subsection.template with subsection=subsection %}
        {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}


# templates/includes/navbar.html
{% load wagtailroutablepage_tags %}
<nav>
  {% for item in nav_sections %}
        <a 
          href="{% if not is_homepage %}{% routablepageurl page 'homepage' %}{% endif %}#section-{{ item.slug }}"
        >
          {{ item.title }}
        </a>
  {% endfor %}
</nav>


# templates/sections/section_base.html

<section id="section-{{ subsection.slug }}" class="{{ subsection.content_type|slugify }}">
  {{ subsection.title }}
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock content %}
</section>


# templates/sections/text_section.html

{% extends 'sections/section_base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  {{ subsection.body|richtext }}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It has certainly helped me get clear in my head what I need to do, which is immensely useful for me. Thank you for your time and experience!

Comment: You're welcome! If if this answer helped you @kelceyswain , you can mark it as 'solved'.

Answer (score 2):

If you're building one page using Django templates, you should be able to pass a list of pages to your template using the [get_context()](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/pages.html#customising-template-context) method.

If it's an SPA, you could use AJAX requests to fetch other pages data from the built-in [Wagtail API](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/api/index.html). If it doesn't fully suit your needs, you could still build your own API with e.g. the [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

Comment: I started down this route and got as far as rendering the child pages in iframes under the parent page, but then I couldn't get it to behave like a single page (i.e. without the iframe-ness). I will investigate an API, but that might require me to chuck out Wagtail and go pure Django, which slightly scares me. Thanks!

Comment: You can keep Wagtail and not use its built-in API. Just write your own DRF code like you would in any normal Django project.

Comment: Also, I don't understand why not using iframes would be a problem. If you can get your page data, what difference does it make if put inside an iframe or a div/section/ul/whatever ?

Comment: And writing AJAX views with Django is scary at first but not so complicated as it seems. Have a look at https://godjango.com/18-basic-ajax/ to understand how these kind of views work, then check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMu0T6L2KRQ&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzTOcOVdZF-th7BS_GYGguAS for a full example with DRF.

Comment: But once again, if you happen to use Django templates and not a full-blown SPA, go the get_context() route.